# PHP mcrypt - mcrypt crypts each string seperatly in concatenated string

Tags: php, string, encryption, mcrypt

I have currently started to work with PHP with a Java background and came accross some issues. I am using mcrypt for a basic encryption using `mcrypt_encrypt ( string $cipher , string $key , string $data , string $mode [, string $iv ] )` the encryption works successfully but there is a case where I need to concatenate 2 strings and then encrypt them but when I do this the output is just as if I had encrypted each string separately then concatenated them afterwards and not before the encryption. What I am doing is this :

```
function base64url_encode($data) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

function base64url_decode($data) {
    return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
}

function encryptCode($data){
    return mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_DES , '12345678' , $data , 'cbc' ,'87654321'); 
}

function decryptCode($data){
    return mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_DES , '12345678' , $data , 'cbc' ,'87654321'); 
}

$id = 'Q2JmDpmqjNmGT4FJ2EkXXITOgc31ZA52';
$toAdd = 'hellothere';
$base64Decoded = base64url_decode($id);
$decrypted = decryptCode($base64Decoded);
$decrypted = $decrypted.$toAdd;
$encryptedID = encryptCode($decrypted);
$base64Encoded = base64url_encode($encryptedID);
print_r($base64Encoded);
```

and then the output is : `Q2JmDpmqjNmGT4FJ2EkXXITOgc31ZA52DG4cvxVuJVnkcrINN0Zt9g`

I am aware of the weakness of DES but I need it in this case so please no comments about that. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: 'myKey' and 'myIV' are not acceptable values so the code you posted will not work at all as is.  You should include real code so we know what your are actually doing here.

Comment: @billynoah yes I am aware that they are not acceptable values but any key or iv causes the same output so it is not the real issue here, I just put those instead of the real values but no matter what the iv and key are the issue still persists

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding bugs dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: If you want help then post example code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Amroelaswar - I tried your code as posted, substituting real values that work in those functions and I did not get the result you described.  So at the moment, you have not provided any way to reproduce the issue you described.  This is why you need to post actual code - otherwise the most likely scenario is your question will soon be closed.

Comment: @billynoah done, and the issue still persists no matter what the values of the key and iv are, this is really not the issue I can assure you that.

Comment: @zaph Added full code with output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say why `mcrypt_encrypt` is not respecting the `CBC` mode of operation (without seeing actual input and output, I'm assuming it's acting as `ECB`). Perhaps `mcrypt`'s default null padding algorithm (`0x00`) is causing issues? I can say that `mcrypt` is abandonware for ~10 years now, so I wouldn't spend the energy trying to figure that out. Use **libsodium**, or, failing that, at least **openssl**.

[This post by Scott Arciszewski](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong) explains the issues with `mcrypt` in PHP.

**Update**

I ran your provided code and [made some additional modifications](https://3v4l.org/nv7UJ) to demonstrate that CBC mode was working as expected. Here is the code I ran:

```
function base64url_encode($data) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

function base64url_decode($data) {
    return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
}

function encryptCode($data){
    return mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_DES , '12345678' , $data , 'cbc' ,'87654321'); 
}

function decryptCode($data){
    return mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_DES , '12345678' , $data , 'cbc' ,'87654321'); 
}

$id = 'Q2JmDpmqjNmGT4FJ2EkXXITOgc31ZA52';
$base64Decoded = base64url_decode($id);
$decrypted = decryptCode($base64Decoded);
print_r($decrypted."\n");
print_r("\n\n");

# Make the new plaintext string
$toAdd = 'hellothere';
$additionalCipherText = encryptCode($toAdd);
$additionalEncoded = base64url_encode($additionalCipherText);
print_r("Additional cipher text: ".$additionalEncoded."\n");
print_r("\n\n");

# Concatenate the plaintext and encrypt
$plaintext = $decrypted.$toAdd;
$cipherText = encryptCode($plaintext);
$base64Encoded = base64url_encode($cipherText);
print_r("     New cipher text: ".$base64Encoded."\n");
print_r("Original cipher text: ".$id.$additionalEncoded."\n");
print_r("\n\n");

# Try the reverse order
$plaintext = $toAdd.$decrypted;
$cipherText = encryptCode($plaintext);
$base64Encoded = base64url_encode($cipherText);
print_r("     New cipher text: ".$base64Encoded."\n");
print_r("Original cipher text: ".$additionalEncoded.$id."\n");
```

I received the following output:

```
��t
anEncryptedId


Additional cipher text: paTJPP5mr-65c1OKybvB1A


     New cipher text: Q2JmDpmqjNmGT4FJ2EkXXITOgc31ZA52DG4cvxVuJVnkcrINN0Zt9g
Original cipher text: Q2JmDpmqjNmGT4FJ2EkXXITOgc31ZA52paTJPP5mr-65c1OKybvB1A


     New cipher text: paTJPP5mr-69piYC2Ep0BM1tiph63ZFqdg_whovwRh0-4AD37H2JPQ
Original cipher text: paTJPP5mr-65c1OKybvB1AQ2JmDpmqjNmGT4FJ2EkXXITOgc31ZA52
```

As you can see, encrypting just `$toAdd` by itself and concatenating with the provided cipher text is *not* the same as concatenating the plaintexts and encrypting. You can see that the 33rd character of the Base64-encoded output is where the differences start, which makes sense: the 33rd character of Base64 is the start of the 25th byte of the cipher text. In DES, the block size is `64 bits / 8 bytes`, so the first three blocks will be encrypted identically. The following block would be modified by the `^` operation of the previous block's cipher text where the `IV` would otherwise be used.

I repeated this operation with the opposite order of the two plaintext inputs. Again, I saw that the first 12 characters of the Base64 output (12 chars -> 8 bytes) are identical, and then there are differences. This is expected, as the original plaintext does not end on a full block boundary, so the new "second block" is not identical to the original "second block". The CBC operation works successfully here to "jumble" the second block.

I would double check the code around the handling of this data and ensure that you are performing the operations (and in the order) you think you are.

Comment: Every indication is that `mcrypt`, for all its failures, properly executes CBC mode correctly. My bet would be the null padding and concatenatyion that is not propogate the padding. The answer is more a comment.

Comment: Why is it that the `$id` is the same when encrypted alone or with concatenated text ? This the part I dont understand, I am doing the same procedure in java and the output is different why is that ? The encrypted data needs to be manipulated in php and in java but php seems to be doing something diffetent. Normally adding anything to `$id` should change the whole output and not just the end

Comment: @Amroelaswar The chosen variable names are horrible and make following the code difficult. Names such as `$base64Decoded`, `$decrypted`, `$base64Encoded` leave the reader wondering what is what? Good naming is the first step toward producing decent understandable code.

Comment: @zaph the code is simple enough for tge naming to not cause that much trouble but will keep your advice in mind, would you happen to have any idea what is happening ?

Comment: I would also like to mention that in java I am ising pkcs5 padding and I am not sure how this works in php so the issue is either a padding issue or an issue with the concatenated string but I dont know how to fix it

Comment: And could you please tell me what is this `��t` ? I am also getting it but don't understand why its there.

Comment: Also when I preform the decryption of the output in Java I get as result `anEncryptedId` without the `hellothere` is there something wrong with the concatenation ?

Comment: Why is your expectation that concatenating plaintext would modify the encryption of the first *n* identical blocks? That's not how CBC works. As I stated above, the first piece of plaintext is 3 blocks exactly, so if you encrypt those blocks with the same `key` and `IV`, it doesn't matter what follows them, the output will be identical.

Comment: The `��t` is part of the decrypted message. You only provided the cipher text for `$id`, not the original plaintext, so we can't see why your encryption operation is including it. It may be accidental inclusion of an IV, bad encoding of the plaintext, etc. Show your entire code if you want us to be able to help further.